# generate a csv file

Tags: shell-script, scripting, csv, columns

I have a script that generates a `.txt` file.

That file have `tab-delimited` columns.
The number of columns vary depending on the input file.

How can I convert that `.txt` file to csv format? I want to have the columns in the `.txt` file be in separate columns in the csv file.

sample:

`.txt` file:

```
header1    header2   header3            header4
1          B         423.sagd.32        333 
2          A         YXTS.a324.gfd33    555 
3          F         343.asr            222
4          D         cbs.98st.asd       4232
```

CSV file (expected output):

```
       A          B         C                  D 
 1     header1    header2   header3            header4
 2     1          B         423.sagd.32        333 
 3     2          A         YXTS.a324.gfd33    555 
 4     3          F         343.asr            222
 5     4          D         cbs.98st.asd       4232
```

Note: The file do not have a fixed number of columns or rows.

Comment: What do you mean with expected output if that's not clearly not a CSV?

Comment: CSV means [Comma-Separated Values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values). The exemplified output is _not_ a CSV file.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing magical about a .csv file. It just means comma (occasionally tab) separated values.

```
mv myfile.txt myfile.csv
```

done

Comment: I tried that but when I look at the csv file, all  the columns in the .txt file are all in column A when I open the csv file in excel.

Comment: Are you using spaces or tabs?

Comment: i am using tabs

Comment: Hmm... this seems to be specific to how Excel is choosing to import the data. Im sure you can set the defaults somewhere. I just tried it out and if you import the csv it will delimit properly, but opening it doesn't seem to. This is an excel setting however and not linux related.  Just as a side note, LibreOffice Calc seems to parse the delimiters correctly every time for me.

Comment: @pinkpostit
you can try comma as a separator. For me tabs and spaces do not work, but comma does

Answer (score 0):

To transform a tab-delimited file ta a comma-delimited file:

```
$ tr '\t' ',' <input.txt >output.csv
```

This will do a naive replacement of all tabs into commas.

If your data contains commas already, then those data fields needs to be quoted.  This is a non-trivial operation. It is best to use a CSV-aware tool to do it, like  [`csvkit`](http://csvkit.readthedocs.io/):

```
$ csvformat -t input.txt >output.csv
```